# A function javascript not defined?

Tags: javascript, function, defined

I declare my function in javascript, but when I execute the code it appears “function javascript not defined”, does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Attach the code :)

Comment: Share the code :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test(){
  alert('Test')
}

var btn = document.getElementById('testButton');
btn.addEventListener("click", test);
```

```css
html { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
body { padding: 20px }
```

```html
<html>
<p>Here is a generic example of using a JavaScript function in HTML.</p>
<button id="testButton">Test</button>
</html>
```